# angular test case failing to return the selected identifier

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, angular-test

I have the below angular test case which is failing because `setSlug` was not run before the `getSlug`. In my `table.component.html`, I am not sure when to call `setSlug` function to make the below test case to pass. Please find the stackblitz code for more details https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcvwph

```
it('should return slug on button click', () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TableComponent);
    let tableIns = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let butt = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#pqr-lmn')).nativeElement;
    butt.click();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(tableIns.getSlug()).toEqual('pqr-lmn');
    });
  });
```

Comment: You have to modified your Component ts file.

    `setSlug(slug) {    
       this.selectedSlug  = slug;
      }`

and try to call setslug function before your butt declared in spec file

   `tableIns.setSlug('pqr-lmn')`

Comment: Do you mean in my table.component.html, I need to have something like <a  (click)="setSlug(eachCustomer.slug);getSlug()" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" id={{eachCustomer.slug}} role="button">View Info</a>

Comment: no i mean you have to modified your component ts file only. not html. `Is your Selectedslug is working properly on html ???`

Comment: Yes, I have modified ts. but where to call setSlug in html is not clear to me?